# visual studio community 2015 debugging access is denied

Tags: vb.net

Just joined so excuse my presentation

Sometimes when running my code in Debug Mode a MS window pops up "Access is Denied". I then have to shut off my computer to get it working again. A hassle and time lost.

A simpler solution for me was the following without shutting the computer off.

Go to Tools - Options - Debugging - General and I have the following two boxes checked "Use Managed Compatability Mode" and "Enable Edit and Continue". I uncheck these boxes and click on OK and then it runs just fine.
The next run thru in debug I just check these boxes again and it runs just fine. Doing the following appears to unblock the clogged drain.
Hope this helps someone.
thanks

Comment: I think this question belongs to superuser.

Comment: Run a ProcessMonitor Trace to see which RegKey returns Access Denied, then go ahead and create the regkey if it doesn't exist or change its permissions.